# Python - Compute average of integers in dictionary values (nested lists)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, average

It is so hard to describe my question in words so here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

I have a dictionary ...

```
aDict= {'user1':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'user2': [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]}
```

I want to compute averages of numbers in the same index in the nested loop.

Ideal result I would like to get is...

```
anotherDict = {'user' : [[1.5 , 2.5 , 3.5 ],[ 4.5 , 5.5 , 6.5 ]]}
```

1.5 = average of 1 from key-user1.values[0][0] and 2 from key-user2.values[0][0]
2.5 = average of 2 from key-user1.values[0][1] and 3 from key-user2.values[0][1]
... so on...
6.5 = average of 6 from key-user1.values[1][2] and 7 from key-user2.values[1][2]

I am really new to python and I really apologize for the difficult explanation of my problem.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are you certain about the length of lists in values of aDict?

Comment: yeah length of lists in the values of aDict is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following nested comprehension using lots of `zip(*...)` transpositioning:

```
aDict= {'user1':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'user2': [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]}
[[sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*vals)] for vals in zip(*aDict.values())]
# [[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]]
```

In Python2, you'd have to take some measures to get `float` values, e.g.:

```
[[1.0*sum(x)/len(x) for x in zip(*vals)] for vals in zip(*aDict.values())]
```

Comment: You can do `from __future__ import division` to get Python 3 style division in Python 2.2+

Comment: Thank you! couldn't think of zip function before!

Answer (score 0):

`map`+list comprehension way of @schwobaseggl's solution:

```
print([list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x),zip(*v))) for v in zip(*aDict.values())])
```

And to assign it to a new dict:

```
d={'user':[list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x),zip(*v))) for v in zip(*aDict.values())]}
```

Or `map` + `map` way of @schwobaseggl's solution:

```
print(list(map(lambda v: list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x),zip(*v))),zip(*aDict.values()))))
```

And to assign it to a new dict:

```
d={'user':list(map(lambda v: list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x),zip(*v))),zip(*aDict.values())))}
```

Do `from __future__ import division` if version under 3 and over 2.2, to get python 3 style division

They all output:

```
[[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]]
```